# Java hex to decimal incorrect conversions

Tags: java, arrays, hex, decimal

I've recently been having this issue where whenever I enter a value for my `hexToDecimal()` method it always outputs some random values that are not the conversions for the entered value at all. For example, if I were to type `ABC`, it would then output `CCCCCC`. I believe it may be a problem in the switch case statement with the `hexVal` but I don't know how to go about and fix it. Here is the method itself below:

```
public static void hexToDecimal() {

    System.out.println("Enter your hexadecimal number (in uppercase)");
    numHexadecimal = input.next();
    hexArray = numHexadecimal.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < hexArray.length; i ++) {
        switch (hexArray [i]) {
        case 'G': case 'H': case 'I': case 'J': case 'K':
        case 'L': case 'M': case 'N': case 'O': case 'P':
        case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S': case 'T': case 'U':
        case 'V': case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z':
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number!"); 
            numHexadecimal = input.next(); 
            hexArray = numHexadecimal.toCharArray(); break;
        default: break;
    }

    int intNum = Integer.valueOf(numHexadecimal, 16);

    int digit;
    digit = intNum % 16;

    switch (digit) {
        case 15: hexVal+="F"; break;
        case 14: hexVal+="E"; break;
        case 13: hexVal+="D"; break;
        case 12: hexVal+="C"; break;
        case 11: hexVal+="B"; break;
        case 10: hexVal+="A"; break;
        case 9:  hexVal+="9"; break;
        case 8:  hexVal+="8"; break;
        case 7:  hexVal+="7"; break;
        case 6:  hexVal+="6"; break;
        case 5:  hexVal+="5"; break;
        case 4:  hexVal+="4"; break;
        case 3:  hexVal+="3"; break;
        case 2:  hexVal+="2"; break;
        case 1:  hexVal+="1"; break;
        case 0:  hexVal+="0"; break;
        default: hexVal+=Integer.toString(digit);          
    }

    intNum = intNum/16;

    for (int j = hexVal.length()-1; j >= 0; j--)
        System.out.print(hexVal.charAt(j));
    }

}
```

Comment: The main problem I can see is the misuse of the switch statement. After each block, you should use a break statement or the flow of control will pass to the next case.

Comment: Java has built in systems to convert between hexadecimal and decimal. To go from an hexdecimal to decimal, you can use `Integer.parseInt(stringValue, 16)`. More details can be found on this guide here: https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/conversion/decimal_hexadecimal.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is rather large and uses a lot of repeated code. I would recommend condensing it down and leveraging some of the built in systems for converting between Hexdecimal and Integers. Something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sampleHex = "83ABC";
    int val = hexToDecimal(sampleHex);
    System.out.println("Value: " + val);
}

private static int hexToDecimal(String value) {
    //Store the valid characters for easy referencing
    char[] validCharacters = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    //Remove white space and make sure all alphabet characters are upper case
    char[] digits = value.strip().toUpperCase().toCharArray();

    //Leverage a named loop to move on to the next digit when determined valid
    outerLoop:
    for(char digit : digits) {
        for(char valid : validCharacters) {
            if(digit == valid)
              continue outerLoop;
        }
        //The character wasn't in your valid list, so declare an error and return a value of -1
        System.out.println("Invalid character given.");
        return -1;
    }
    //Use the built in library tools to convert the value
    return Integer.parseInt(value, 16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Hunter said, Java already has this capability. 
But if you want to write your own, here is a version that uses fewer built-in system calls.

```
   public static int hexToDecimal(String s) {
      int ans = 0;
      String str = s.toLowerCase();
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
         ans *= 16;
         char c = str.charAt(i);
         if ( (c >= '0') && (c <= '9')) {
            ans += c - '0';
         } else {
            switch (c) {
            case 'a':
            case 'b':
            case 'c':
            case 'd':
            case 'e':
            case 'f':
               ans += 10 + c - 'a';
               break;
            default:
               // TODO: handle format error
               break;
            }
         }
      }
      return ans;
   }
```

The body of the for loop can be reduced to

```
   ans *= 16;
   ans += Character.digit( c, 16 );
```

This can be improved by working from right-to-left rather than left-to-right to help avoid overflow problems for large values, as would using long instead of int.